# Vercel Postgres Connection Error: missing_connection_string

Tags: postgresql, next.js, vercel

For only a single query I am getting the following error when I try to query the postgres database for my NextJS project hosted on Vercel: `VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.`

The query in question is:

```
const data = await sql<Book>`
    SELECT * FROM books
    WHERE ${
        worldId && seriesId
            ? `world=${ worldId } AND series=${ seriesId }`
            : worldId && !seriesId
                ? `world=${ worldId }`
                : !worldId && seriesId
                    ? `seriesId=${ seriesId }`
                    : ''
    }
    ORDER BY publish_date ASC
`;
return data;
```

My POSTGRES_URL is set in my `.env` file and all my other queries are working. I confirmed that my environment variables are the same in my dashboard on Vercel and in my code. To begin with, I'm not sure why I would ever get this error, as the docs explicitly say that the `sql` template literal tag automatically connects to the database, so I should not need to explicitly establish a connection.

I have also tried restarting the server, to no avail. What else can I do to resolve this? Any help is appreciated.